# Merging two files column and row-wise in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, merge

I would like to merge two files, column and row-wise but am having difficulty doing so with bash. Here is what I would like to do.

File1:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

File2:

```
2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 1
```

Expected output file:

```
1/2 2/3 3/4
4/5 5/6 6/7
7/8 8/9 9/1
```

This is just an example. The actual files are two 1000x1000 data matrices.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: do the files have blank lines as displayed? are the files guaranteed to contain the same number of rows and columns? and if not, what are you supposed to do with 'left over' columns and/or rows? consider reviewing [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your question accordingly, eg, add the code you've tried so far and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: `paste -d '/' file1 file2`?

Comment: @daniu: that generates output like `1 2 3/2 3 4`

Comment: No space between lines, columns are space separated. It a matrix of exact dimensions, no left over columns. In this example case its 3x3. I tried paste, join.

Comment: please update the question with some examples of your attempts using `paste` and `join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use `paste` + `awk`

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ n=NF/2; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s/%s ", $i, $(i+n); printf "\n"; }'
```

Note that this script adds a trailing space after the last value. This can be avoided with a more complicated `awk` script or by piping the output through an additional command, e.g.

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ n=NF/2; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s/%s ", $i, $(i+n); printf "\n"; }' | sed 's/ $//'
```

`awk` solution without additional `sed`. Thanks to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler). (I knew it is possible but was too lazy to think about this.)

```
awk '{ n=NF/2; pad=""; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) { printf "%s%s/%s", pad, $i, $(i+n); pad=" "; } printf "\n"; }'
```

Comment: Using `awk '{ n=NF/2; pad=""; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) { printf "%s%s/%s", pad, $i, $(i+n); pad=" "; } printf "\n"; }'` avoids trailing blanks.

Answer (score 1):

`paste` + `perl` version that works with an arbitrary number of columns without having to hold an entire file in memory:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | perl -MList::MoreUtils=pairwise -lane '
    my @a = @F[0 .. (@F/2 - 1)]; # The values from file1
    my @b = @F[(@F/2) .. $#F]; # The values from file2
    print join(" ", pairwise { "$a/$b" } @a, @b); # Merge them together again'
```

It uses the non-standard but useful [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) module; install through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client.

Comment: Thanks! I guess something like this should work! But is there a way to do this for a 1000x1000 matrix?

Comment: @RameshArunkumar You should mention things like the dimensions you're actually dealing with in your question...

Comment: You're right. I modified the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- no blank lines in files
- both files have the same number of rows
- both files have the same number of fieldds
- no idea how many rows and/or fields we'll have to deal with

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '

# first file (FNR==NR):

FNR==NR { for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++)          # loop through fields
              { line[FNR,i]=$(i) }          # store field in array; array index = row number (FNR) + field number (i)
          next                              # skip to next line in file
        }

# second file:

        { pfx=""                            # init printf prefix as empty string
          for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++)          # loop through fields
              { printf "%s%s/%s",           # print our results:
                    pfx, line[FNR,i], $(i)  # prefix, corresponding field from file #1, "/", current field
                pfx=" "                     # prefix for rest of fields in this line is a space
              }
          printf "\n"                       # append linefeed on end of current line
        }
' file1 file2
```

**NOTES**:

- remove comments to declutter code
- memory usage will climb as the size of the matrix increases (probably not an issue for the smallish fields and OPs comment about a 1000 x 1000 matrix)

The above generates:

```
1/2 2/3 3/4
4/5 5/6 6/7
7/8 8/9 9/1
```